# Are there any downsides to running Elasticsearch on a multi-purpose (i.e. non-dedicated) cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I just set up an Elasticsearch (ES) 3 node cluster using one of GKE's click to deploy configurations. Each node is of n1-standard-4 machine type (4vCPUs/15GB RAM). I have always run ES on clusters dedicated to that single purpose (performance reasons, separation of concerns, make my life easier to debug machine faults), and currently, this GKE cluster is the same.

However, i have a group of batch jobs i would like to port to run on a GKE cluster. Since it updates several large files, I would like this to also run on a stateful cluster (just like ES) so I can move updated files to the cloud once a day rather than round tripping on every run. The batch jobs in question run at 5min, 15min or daily frequency for about 18hrs every day.

My question now is, what is the best way to deploy this batch process given the existing ES cluster...

- Create an entirely new cluster?
- Create another node pool?
- Create a separate namespace and increase the cluster's autoscaling?
- Some other approach i'm missing?

*Note: I'm a few days into using GKE and containerization in general*

Comment: Hello @WittyID, just to know if I understand you correctly, batch jobs run for 18 hours a day every 5,15 or daily frequency time? If we look at it from money perspective I would say [autoscaler](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler) would be the best, since it wouldn't take more resources when cluster wouldn't need them, like whole new cluster and another node pool would, since it would be 6h working time of new cluster/new node pool for nothing, unless you will use them for something else. Let me know if that answer your question.

Comment: Hi @jt97, you're correct, i'd only need to have resources provisioned for 18hrs every day (current doing this with spot instances on AWS). However, my question is more about if doing this with autoscaler within the same cluster would in any way affect elasticsearch esp with all the ES specific yaml configs? Also with regards to the 6h node pool doing nothing comment, wouldn't I be able to avoid this on a new cluster or node pool with a minimum scaling parameter of zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my knowledge I would go for another [nodepool](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/node-pools) or [autoscaler](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler).

> Create an entirely new cluster?

For me it would be an overkill for just running the jobs.

> Create another node pool?

I would say it's the best option equally with the autoscaler, create a new nodepool just for the jobs which would scale down to 0 if there is nothing more to do.

---

> Create a separate namespace and increase the cluster's autoscaling?

Same as another node pool, but from my point of view if you would like to do that, then you would have to label your nodes to the Elasticsearch, then jobs can't take any resources from them, so answering your question from comment

> my question is more about if doing this with autoscaler within the same cluster would in any way affect elasticsearch esp with all the ES specific yaml configs?

It shouldn't, as I said above, you can always [label](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/node-pools#deploying_services_to_specific_node_pools) the 3 specific nodes(default nodepool) to work only with elasticsearch then nothing will take their resources, cluster will rescale when it will need more resources for jobs and rescale to 3 ES nodes when jobs end their 18hrs work.

---

> Also with regards to the 6h node pool doing nothing comment, wouldn't I be able to avoid this on a new cluster or node pool with a minimum scaling parameter of zero?

Based on [gcp documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler#minimum_and_maximum_node_pool_size) it would work for nodepool, but not for new cluster.

> If you specify a minimum of zero nodes, an idle node pool can scale down completely. However, at least one node must always be available in the cluster to run system Pods.

---

**tldr** Go for the autoscaler or another nodepool, if you're worried about resources for your ES label the 3 nodes just for ES.

---

I hope it answer your question. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: I was crawling my way to the similar conclusions while second-guessing myself at every turn. Thanks for clarifying and giving me the confidence to proceed. I'll probably run a mirror of our current production setup for a week or so to ensure I've done things correctly. For what its worth, i'm really loving Kubernetes so far.

Comment: PS: Just got an email titled "Google Kubernetes Engine is introducing a cluster management fee on June 6, 2020" ($0.10 per cluster per hour irrespective of size or topology). This simplifies making a decision to use a single cluster.